# Devex Timeout Popup doesn't dissapear when time is up

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I use the devex time out control which is described in the following link.
[DevExpress Timeout Control](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3302)
It works with the session time out value which is set in web.config. Let's say if the session timeout is set to 30 minutes, then after 29 minutes, a pop up appears and shows count down from 60 and asking the user if he wants to continue his session. If the user doesn't click Okay, then the user is redirected to the login page at the end of the count down. This is the way it's supposed to work, but when sometimes I find the page being stuck, count down set to 0 and the browser tries to redirect but some how can't. I think it might have something to do browser not being in focus. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Best place to ask is the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Comment: I already did. They couldn't come up with solution. I finally figured that it's caused by "document.location". If you minimize the browser and put focus on some other application and when browser is not in focus, call to document.location is made, then request is successfully done and response is received, but the rendering of the web site hangs and doesn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

DevEx Timeout control uses document.location to navigate to login page when session times out. document.location doesn't work properly when browser is minimized and not having focus. Using window.location fixed the issue in IE, Chrome and Firefox.